# Flutter Google Map Places can't show exact street name?

Tags: flutter

Hello everyone I am trying to find address with TextField. It works fine except one detail.
Problem is, if I write where I try to find my exact address `lat` and `long` find it perfectly.
Example:

[image]

The red line as you can see, it is correct address and I can add a marker it is fine.
The problem starts here;

If I click my current location (also providing with GetX), I can reach street or main road name (Nizamettin) but I can't reach alley name which is red line at the screenshots.(250.sk.)
`lat` and `long` are true.

This is my `getMyAdress` code:

```
void getMyAdress(lat, long) async {
    try {
      List<Placemark> placemark =
          await GeocodingPlatform.instance.placemarkFromCoordinates(lat, long);
      Placemark place = placemark[0];

      currentAdress =
          '${place.subLocality}, Mahalle: ${place.street},  Şehir: ${place.subAdministrativeArea}';
      updateModel(currentAdress); //Modelimize gelen adresi gönderdik
      adresim.add(
          "Mahalle: ${place.street},Şehir: ${place.subAdministrativeArea}"); // Adresim listesine gelen adresi gönderdik

      update();
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('hata mesajı ' + e.toString());
      update();
    }
  }
```

And this is my `getAdressFromText` code

```
void getAdressFromText(String adresim) async {

        try {
          List<Location> locationss =
              await GeocodingPlatform.instance.locationFromAddress(adresim);
          Location adresPlace = locationss[0];
          updateModel(adresPlace.toString());
    
          textLat = adresPlace.latitude;
          textLong = adresPlace.longitude;
          debugPrint(
              "${adresPlace.latitude.toString()}, ${adresPlace.longitude.toString()}");
        } catch (e) {
          Get.snackbar("Hata", e.toString());
        }
      }
```

So, how can I get exact adress name on Text widget?

[image]

Comment: maps and geolocator are difference apis. both have different rules and naming conventions of locations.

Comment: so what do you suggest for getting addresses ?

Answer (score 0):

**HERE IS SOLUTION FOR COMMUNITY**

If we put this  `Placemark place = placemark[1];` instead of this `Placemark place = placemark[0];` we can reach the exact address.

Example:

```
address =
        '${place2.street}, ${place2.administrativeArea}, ${place2.subAdministrativeArea}, ${place2.thoroughfare}, ${place2.country}';
```